# Markup incorrect but can't find the error

Tags: html, markup

I've started the css to a website, but am having some markup issues with my HTML

here is a link to the code.

http://pastebin.com/dTRH263t

seems I've not closed some div's but when I look back at it can't see the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What posted is a URL of a pastebin page that contains the content of your PHP file. Not an HTML file.

Comment: I think you need to look again carefully, thats just so I don't have to change it when I convert it to wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this had a closing tag missing the "/" closing bit.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Start using http://validator.w3.org/

Not counting php issues, there we have:

1. Unclosed div on 26
2. Unclosed div on 27
3. In img tags empty attributes (set values or delete)

Comment: I've used this and can't seem to find a problem with it when I look at my code, you can see at the bottom i've closed these div's